# How does electrical current have energy? (when electrons move very slowly through circuit )

Tags: current

I'm interested to know how electric current carries energy. I understand that the huge amount of electrons pass at one point through conductor, but they move slowly. So I do not understand how much energy they have.

Comment: Are you going to delete this question, too?

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this on this site already, read those and their answers to get a better understanding of the subject. Also the amount of available electrical energy is not directly related to the amount or speed of the electrons themselves. Voltage difference also plays a huge part.

Comment: I ask it because a user with this very same screen name asked a very similar question about a week ago, and after I had answered it, he deleted it, along with my answer.

Comment: Are you going to delete this question, too? – Janka if I wanna why not

Comment: Deleting a question after people have put effort into decent answers is considered rude.

Comment: The reason why people don't like this question is, it is off-topic for the group.  The group is intended for questions about the _design_ of electronic devices (e.g., "how do I ...?").  Your question is about the _physics_---it is a "why...?" question.

Comment: "but they move slowly" - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54995/how-is-possible-for-current-to-flow-so-fast-when-charge-flows-so-slow

Answer (score 2):

> How does electrical current have energy?

Voltage and current together can transfer energy (do work) because volts x amps = power and the time integral of power is energy.

For a rotating mechanical system, power = speed (radians per second) x torque so power is the product of torque and speed but either isn't power or energy on its own.